# KQL summarize by count then take those with a count above x

Tags: kql

I have a situation where I am trying to count all instances of something, then I want to see where the count is greater than X for my own purposes

Right now I have all my clauses, then `summarize count() by X, Y, Z` where `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are columns. This gives me about 35 lines, but a lot of them have a count of 1 and do not interest me. Is there a way I can further filter this to see those where the total count is greater than a number I choose, for ex 20 or so?

I tried adding `where count>20` but this gets me a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `|where count_ >20` does the trick. I missed the `_` initially